# How to make project folder act as system folder in Eclipse Luna

Tags: c, eclipse, include-path, eclipse-luna

I'm working on a porting of the net-snmp library. I started by importing the parts of the code that I need in my Eclipse Luna project, running on Lubuntu Linux 15.10. I don't want to modify every single file from (for instance)

```
#include <net-snmp/net-snmp-config.h>
```

to

```
#include "net-snmp/net-snmp-config.h"
```

I don't want to install net-snmp in my system either, to avoid confusion.

How do I tell Eclipse to look in the project root for header files?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I found a way:

- go to Project Properties
- under C/C++ Build go to Settings
- under the tab "Tool Settings" go to "Includes" under "GCC C Compiler"
- Click the "+Add" icon under "Include paths (-l)"
- Click "Workspace" and then select the folder